# Google Not Resolving Domain

Tags: domain-name-system, google

I am stumped on this one. Our DNS seems to be correct, and can access the site with no problems. However, Google seems to be having issues with it, as well as SPF and DKIM records showing as "dkim=temperror (dns failure for signature) and spf=temperror (google.com: error in processing during lookup of xyz123@heartnhomeindiana.org: DNS error)".

Every DNS check is good, except from Google: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/www.heartnhomeindiana.org

This has caused our site not to get crawled, as well as messages to gmail addresses to be flagged as SPAM.

Any help would be really wonderful. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that working DNS records have been cached and that you recently changed the authoritative name servers for the domain?  At the moment, the host names of the authoritative name servers, `ns1.ftrackns.com` and `ns2.ftrackns.com` do not resolve – most likely due to not having a glue record configured for the `ftrackns.com` domain.

Comment: Have you incremented your SOA Serial recently? If not Google (and others) won't see any changes to your domain's DNS

Answer (score 0):

Anthony, the primary IP for the server was not used in the child nameservers for ns1.ftackns.com - can't believe it. All seems to be working now. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: You have online tools to troubleshoot DNS configuratios: https://zonemaster.net/ and https://dnsviz.net/  They should be your first stop to investigate.

Comment: Hi Mike. Glad you got it working. [se] sites are not like other online forums so I'd suggest you take the [tour] to get an overview of how they work. It's also worth taking a look at [ask] and [answer]. Welcome to Serverfault!

Comment: Going forward, I will post within the model of Stack Exchange.